# How to use combination of Jquery Datatables, Ajax and Pagination in rails for RestClient API response?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

Assume I have SAMPLE table which contains 3000 records in it.
Now then I hit the API url using Rest-Client which gives all records from the table. But I need only 30 records at a time.
On click of the pagination of Datatable the next set of records should be fetched.
So how this implementation should be done using a combination of Jquery-Datatable, Ajax, Pagination and Rest-Client in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ajax-datatables-rails](https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails), it uses all the toolset you asked for. Except RestClient, it handles the requests for you.

I you have a specific question, we could help you with that too. I'm currently working on a project that has this implemented.